# Are photons the sources for the electron field?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, photons, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

I'm self-learning QFT, so please excuse my inaccuracies.

Consider the complete quantum electrodynamic action:

$$\int d^4x \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu \partial _ \mu - m)\psi + A_\nu J^\nu - \frac{1}{4}F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}$$

where:
$$J^\nu = e\bar{\psi} \gamma^\nu \psi$$

Classically, since particles are not thought of as fields, we say that the four current $J^\nu$ is the source of the electromagnetic field and there is no other way around. In QFT, there is particle field duality, so particles are fields. The only term I recognize being the source, for the electron field let's say, is $A_\nu$. Of course having other fields, like the gluon, create other coupling terms. But in electrodynamics, can we say the source for the electron field is the 4-potential $A_u$?

Comment: A source term for $\psi$ should look like $J \psi$ and not $\bar{\psi} A \psi$

Comment: maybe this answer of mine to a different question  will help clarify the concept of "field" https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131968/what-is-the-electromagnetic-field-and-what-is-the-higgs-field/131998#131998